# Continuous update UI from Service

Tags: service, bluetooth

I'd be very grateful if somebody can help me. (I'm absolute beginer with Android).
There's a lot of code in the web, but I couldn't find anything suitable for my application.

I've an installation with some sensors connected to Arduino. All input data are collected in a String, and this String is sent via Bluetooth to an Android device every 1~2 seconds (depending on data availability from sensors). Is to be used for hours.

I made an App that receives the data (via Bluetooth) and shows all data in real time update in one layout, with the Bluetooth code in the MainActivity. Works well.

What I need is an App with three different Activities, all using the same String data from Bluetooth, and real time updated.

My question is how to build the App:

-Bluetooth running in a Service, and Activities connected to it?

-Which is a good way for real time update in any of the three Activities?

A similar example could be a weather station, an Android device receiving data via Bluetooth, showing the same weather data in three different layouts, with continous update.
Thanks in advance